# Golang facebook api huandu/facebook Post Description issue

Tags: json, api, facebook-graph-api, go

Hi I am using golang huandu/facebook as Oath client to post articles, But the description and name fields does not get posted, only the status message and the image , link get published.. Please help

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    fb "github.com/huandu/facebook"
)

func main() {
    res, e := fb.Post("/97876588/feed", fb.Params{
        "type": "link",
        "name": "test news is here",
        "caption": "The caption of a link in the post ",
        "picture": "http://img.tvguide.dk/tvnyheder/39ecaf74dbfa71c79225705c0d36bb09.jpg",
        "link":"http://img.tvguide.dk/tvnyheder/39ecaf74dbfa71c79225705c0d36bb09.jpg",
        "description":"hendes lille datter foregik nemlig under helt andre omstændigheder,er Tina Lund.",
        "access_token": "access-token",
    })
    fmt.Println(e)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem , it is just because of i am linking to the jpeg file, when place a proper link it works perfect..